# How to get an Element inside a RadPageView inside a RadMultiPage?

Tags: javascript, html, telerik

I have html-code like this:

```
<telerik:RadMultiPage ID="MultiPage" runat="server">   
   <telerik:RadPageView ID="TablePage" runat="server">  
      <Cx:DataObjectDefinitionTree ID="TableOverview"   runat="server"/>  
   </telerik:RadPageView>  
</telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

I can get the Multipage by this: `var multiPage = $find('<%= MultiPage.ClientID %>');`
But i am not able to get either the `PageView` or the `DataObjectDefinitionTree`.
Though i need the `DataObjectDefinitionTree`.
I tried to get the `PageView` from the `MultiPage` and then the `DataObjectDefinitionTree` from that but that did not work either.

How can i get the `DataObjectDefinitionTree` into an Variable in Javascript?

Edit:
I just want to call two methods from `DataObjectDefinitionTree` (it is basicly the same as a `RadTreeView`).
These methods are `_getAllItems()` and `get_selectedNode()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the Error:
`<%=TableOverview.ClientID %>` gives the wrong ID.
To get the correct ID i had to add the following to my ASPX-Control `DataObjectDefinitionTree`:
`public override string ClientID {

get { return TableTree.ClientID; }

//TableTree is the base object of DataObjectDefinitionTree

}`

Now i get the correct ID when i call `<%=TableOverview.ClientID %>`.
Thanks for your help, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Telerik's Client-Side API is pretty complete, [see by yourself](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip-mutlipage-client-object.html):

```
var multiPage = $find('<%= MultiPage.ClientID %>');
var pageView = multiPage.findPageViewByID("TablePage");
```

As for the `DataObjectDefinitionTree`, you should be able to get the DOM element for the pageView:

```
var domElement = pageView.get_element();
dataObjDefTree = domElement.getElementById('<%=TableOverview.ClientID %>');
```

Or you can try something like this:

```
var dataObjDefTree = document.getElementById('<%=TableOverview.ClientID %>');
```

Comment: Yeah, well i tried it that way and came pretty far (i had something wich seemed like the `DataObjectDefinitionTree` but wasnt if i try it exactly like you i get an Error while `var domElement = pageView.get_element();` because pageView is null...

Comment: pageView is null even if you assign the variable using the first 2 lines (`multiPage.findPageViewByID`)?

Comment: Yes, i used all four lines. And when i use the fifth line `dataObjDefTree` is null as well.

Comment: Ok, then I guess it would help if you tell what you want to do with `DataObjectDefinitionTree`.(Edit your question)

Answer (score 0):

Ok then, the main problem here is How to access your `WebUserControl`'s javascript from the parent page. You'll need to wrap your `DataObjectDefinitionTree`'s content in a div using the same ID as your UserControl. Here is a [link](http://programmerramblings.blogspot.ca/2011/07/clientside-api-for-aspnet-user-controls.html) explaining this.

Then from the UserControl, declare your own functions accessing `RadTreeView`'s Client-Side API (`_getAllItems()` and `get_selectedNode()`).

Comment: Well it does not seem to help. Because since i got my element i have already access to the functions. Now i think i spottet the Error. When i write `$find('<%=TableOverview.ClientID %>')` the ID i get is `CPH_TableOverview` although the ID i need to get is like `ctl00_CPH_TableOverview_TableTree`. Thats the reason the `dataObjDefTree` is null. But why does `$find('<%=TableOverview.ClientID %>')` gives me a wrong ID?